# Why must While and Forever loops be broken with a @(posedge/negedge clock) statement?

Tags: verilog

Can someone explain why `While` and `Forever` loops must be broken with a `@(posedge/negedge clock)` statement? How does it help to avoid a combinational feedback?

[image]

Comment: It's Verilog summary from Carleton university. My teacher used it in class, and said that without the pos/negedge statement, the loop might become infinite when the condition is always true. But I don't understand why?

Comment: The book lacks context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there may be some terminology misunderstandings from the text your teacher refers to. I would have used the term *zero-delay infinite loop* instead of *combinational feedback*

There must be some way of breaking out of a procedural loop having no delays, otherwise time cannot advance. If you had the block

```
always A = B;
```

This is process that executes the assignment `A = B` at time 0, and then loops back with no delay to execute the statement again. Since there is no event or timing control, there is no opportunity to ever be done with the current time step and move on to the next time step. It will be a time 0 infinite loop. It should be written as

```
always @* A = B; // wait for B to change, then execute the assignment.
```

Similarly if you had the `while` loop a

```
...
while (condition == True)
   do_something_with_no_delays;
...
```

unless *do_something* is able to change `condition` to not be true, you get into an infinite loop giving no opportunity for time to advance or even letting other code execute to change the `condition` to false breaking out of the loop.

Synthesis require loops with no delays to have a maximum iteration limit. They will statically unroll the body of the loop do it can create a fixed amount of hardware.

```
integer I = 0;
while (I <10) begin
    I = I + 1;
    ...
end
```

The body of the loop will be replicated 10 times with `I` substituted for each values 0...9 in each iteration.

Most RTL synthesis tools today do not allow procedural loops with embedded delays except as an `always` construct with the delay at the beginning of the loop.

---

### Update:

It would have helped to provide more context to the paragraph you posted. I found a link to the entire document [here](http://www.doe.carleton.ca/%7Egallan/478/pdfs/PeterVrlR.pdf). Although it has a publication date of 2003, I think the contents may be at least 5 years older. Around that time there were a number of commercial tools exploring behavioral synthesis with Verilog, which did not catch on.

The quote from the section you posted is referring to behavioral synthesis coding styles that could break up procedural code into multiple cycles by adding `@(posedge clk)` anywhere in the block, including loops. That synthesis style has mostly been abandoned and the recommended style is one event at the begging of an `always` block as that document explains in section *13. Component Inference*.

I would recommend against using that document anymore as it is very old and inaccurate. You can tell your teacher a key contributor to the development of Verilog language told you so .

Comment: And do_something_with_no_delays being a @(pos/negedge clock) statement makes sure  the time step is advanced, but it might still be an infinite loop (if the condition keeps being true)?

Comment: You can have infinite loops as long as time can advance. The code used to generate a clock is usually written using infinite loop.

Comment: OK, but what I'm asking is why they say we need a @(pos/negedge clock) statement inside the loop?

Comment: See the update in my response.